# How to modify matrix with user inputs in while loop, and break when user inputs string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that modifies the matrix given user inputs in a while loop and continues to receive inputs until the User inputs a string.

This is basically my final goal:

```
for a matrix i=[[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
user input:
2
3
3
3
t

for user inputs, the first integer specifies the row, and the next one following it specifies the column.

expected output: i=[[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I tried several methods, but i still failed to get what I want:

```
while True:
    x=input()   
    y=input()
    if type(y)==int and type(x)==int:
     i[x][y]=1
    else:
      break
print(i)

This outputs original configuartion [[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I also tried this one:

```
while True:
    x=input()
    y=int(input())
    i[x][y]=1
    if x=="t":
        break

print(i)

outputs TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `if type(y)==int ` will _always_ fail because user input is _always_ a string. You need a `try`/`except` to see if the input string can possibly be converted

Comment: With a `try`/`except` this comment won't mean much, but you should also use `isinstance` to check types

Answer (score 0):

[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) return a 'str' so i[x] raises 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Comment: So what should their approach look like?

Comment: @roganjosh - I am not sure I understand your question. Please explain.

Comment: Well if you turn the tables and this was an answer to your question, how would you go about implementing it? It says nothing about what the actual approach should be

Comment: Got it..I thought the solution is obvious - try to convert to int and if it fails ask the user to insert the input again.

Comment: The solution might be obvious to you, but not necessarily if you put yourself in the OP's shoes :)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing several issues here.

First of all, you have to convert the input to list indices, but only if first input (x) is not 't'.
I added this comparison at the beginning of the loop, so we terminate the loop without even bothering about y.

Then, both inputs x and y are converted to int (using int()), and we subtract 1 from each one of them because I understand that the user has to enter "natural" matrix indices (starting at 1), instead of python indices (starting at zero).

```
mat = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

while True:
    x = input()
    if x is 't':
        break;
    else:
        xi = int(x) - 1
        yi = int(input()) - 1

    mat[xi][yi] = 1

print(mat)
```

Note that further input checking would actually be done here, but I kept it minimal for this answer.

An example of input checking function would be the following :

```
def check_x(x_local):
    if len(x_local) is not 1:
        raise ValueError()
    return x_local
```

Which would trigger an exception if the entered input was anything but a single character.
You would then call it in your main program like so :

```
x = check_x(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick :) A little bit of reordering and type conversion during the indexing instead of on input(), fixes a lot of the other issues at play also

```
i=[[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]


while True:

    x=input()
    y=input()

    """ As we're unsure when we'd like to break, lets assume t could be in x or y """
    if x == "t" or y == "t":
        break
    """ Convert both inputs to ints """
    else:
      i[int(x)][int(y)]=1

print(i)
```